# Scheduled Update - publish new draft of an existing and published node

Tags: workbench

Trying to setup a scheduled update of an existing node (Drupal 8.3).

1. I make content changes and setup Moderation State to draft - node is still visible to visitors, and new revisions is saved with changes to node content.
2. I setup scheduled update - Publish single node at certain time, and set Moderation State to Published.
3. Click Save

Result - When I run Scheduled Updates node moderation state changes to draft and is no longer visible to visitors.

Any idea why it doesn't change node moderation state from draft to publish?